# RTF Field Parsing when content ends with '<'

Tags: rtf

I am trying to give below HTML but upon I move to design tab, text was totally altered

HTML : `<strong>Testing<</strong>`

After Parsing : `<strong>Testing&lt;&lt;/strong&gt;</strong>`

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML source is have an extra **<**. Your source should be

```
<strong>Testing</strong>
```

Tridion use HTMLTidy out of the box for RTF parsing unless you have a separate XSLT filter.

Comment: its not an extra character , part of my content

Comment: Did you try the ASCII code for the character?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the issue with Tidy. 
What you can do is create a rewriter that can change < into < at publish time, but it will still stay as gibberish in component as content. Also, it might interfere with your html on a page.

Also, have you tried publishing it? How is it seen on a page?
< > characters are automatically changed to their encoded values so that browsers can differentiate them from opening and closing tags.